# When cutting nails with dremel, can sparks be dangerous?

Tags: metal-cutting

I'm preparing the ceiling in my basement for painting, which means cutting off a ton of nails from the flooring above. I started cutting using my Dremel with the reinforced cutting wheel, but it would shower sparks against the floor joists and ceiling. Are these sparks hot enough to be a fire danger? What are some alternatives?

Comment: "When cutting nails with dremel, can sparks be dangerous?" **Yes. They can get in your eyes**.  Alternative: A false ceiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cutting metal with an abrasive disk will always cause sparks, but they are so small that each spark (which is actually a very hot piece of abrasive or metal) doesn't contain much energy.  They typically can't burn your skin unless you concentrate them in one spot, and will not burn wood or other materials.

If you happen to have a gas can or oily rags or other *highly* flammable material, you should be careful but typical building materials shouldn't cause a concern.  Wear a hat to protect your hair (it can singe) and a face mask or good fitting safety glasses to protect your eyes.

The alternative would be to use something like a reciprocating saw with a metal cutting blade (basically a powered hack-saw).  This would probably put too much force on the nails and might cause them to loosen or even rise slightly.  It's also a heavier tool and would be harder to use.

Comment: It's got a bad word in it, but the point is the same: [Just be careful where those sparks land](https://external-preview.redd.it/e2EfvdaIw17H2fkzZMNuUjjHO9eR3AmT8SiPP_MdFys.jpg?auto=webp&s=b97fa76d4a1efa982b621172432c13a109a04d57)

Answer (score 0):

The experience doing restoration work is **hang around for a few hours after you are done** to see if anything starts to catch.

The usual fail is this: people are grinding til 30 minutes before quitting time, clean up, walk the shop one last time, all good... go to dinner, and on the way back from dinner they see the shop in flames.  Fire Dept. confirms it started in the grinding/cutting area. *That's because it smoldered for an hour or two before it caught in earnest.  The cure is having a 1:30pm cutoff for grinding and hot work.*

Just pointing out, this strategy will let you use a bigger cutoff wheel than a Dremel. That way you're going through them in 2 seconds instead of 2 discs :)

Comment: @RobertMoody sounds like that comment applies to the question moreso than my answer..